# Guava cache configuration to support fixed rate cache refresh

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I have a spring app that uses Guava Cache library for caching `@Service` result. I have the following cache spec:

```
spring:
cache:
  cache-names: teamConfigs
  guava:
    spec: expireAfterWrite=600s,maximumSize=1000
```

However, this config (as far as I understand) would **never** refresh a cached object value if this service call is being made every minute with the following method:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "teamConfigs")
public TeamDto findTeam(String teamId) {
    return ...;
}
```

Is there any way I could hint Guava that it should reload cache on a fixed rate?

Comment: Why wouldn't it refresh the cache? The first call writes to the cache, the next ones only read from the cache, and the evition is thus made 600 seconds after the first call, that wrote to the cache. If you're not sure, test it.

Comment: `expireAfterWrite` means that entries will be expired that long after the first time that entry is loaded.

Comment: @jb The entry is written to DB in another app, so there is no way to know in my app that DB has new value. And I do not want to start using distributed cache for now, unless completely necessary.

Comment: @Louis and that means that after it expires, every call to the Cacheable method would fetch the value from DB, isn't it? Then it's too aggressive behavior, I need just cache update once in a while, not all the time.

Comment: Only for that key, then its another 300 seconds before that expires.

Comment: How is that related to your question? Of couse, if you want to always get the fresher value from the database, you shouldn't use any cache. After 600 seconds, the cache entry will be evicted, so the next method call will read the newest value from the database and rewrite it to the cache, where it will stay there for another 600 seconds.